# golang syslog failure: Unix syslog delivery error

Tags: go, osx-mavericks, syslog

I'm on OSX running Mavericks 10.9.2. I'm trying to get my Revel app logging to syslog. My code is failing on this line:

```
sysLog, err := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_NOTICE|syslog.LOG_LOCAL0, "myApp")
```

with this error:

```
Unix syslog delivery error
```

Syslog is definitely running on my machine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try checking /var/log/system.log to see if there was a more useful error than what Go gave you. You may also want to check out this [article](http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/18/using-syslogappender-on-os-x/).

Comment: I'm successfully writing to syslog from another application. That article is for Java so didn't really apply.

Answer (score 2):

Verify syslog is running or else enable it.

```
$ ps -aux | grep syslog
root 11703  0.0  0.4 14424 1992  -  IsJ   9:17AM 0:00.01 /usr/sbin/syslogd -ss
```

Now verify syslog is running in the expected local address. The log/syslog package looks for syslog in /var/run/syslog or /dev/log. If it does not find it   there, you see the *"Unix syslog delivery error"* as per http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/syslog/syslog_unix.go.

To find the local address of syslog use the *sockstat* command

```
$sockstat
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS      
root     login      12104 3  dgram  -> /var/run/logpriv  
root     login      11791 3  dgram  -> /var/run/logpriv
root     cron       11754 4  dgram  -> /var/run/logpriv
root     syslogd    11703 4  dgram  /var/run/log
root     syslogd    11703 5  dgram  /var/run/logpriv
```

In above case, syslog is running at /var/run/log. So, I created a symlink from /var/run/log to /var/log/syslog and the error goes away.

```
$ln -sf /var/run/log /var/run/syslog
```

Comment: I'm on a Mac so I ran lsof -p. I got a lot of output but do see this: syslogd 10273 root    6u    unix 0x4a2e6ea3c4e6ca4f       0t0          /var/run/syslog

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to a Mac. Can you verify syslog is configured and working correctly, using the command `logger "Test message from logclient"`. It should write to a file in /var/log/ as configured in /etc/syslog.conf.

Comment: Syslog is definitely running on my machine. I can write to it manually and via a different application.